# How to obtain an array of values from a RegEx operation on a multiline variable in Perl?

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, variables, multiline

After a couple of days reading StackExchange posts and endless trial and error, I decided to ask the world to help me.

I have the following *multiline* string stored in `$received_data` and I need to print just the values of the transfer speed on every line.

Here is my code snippet:

```
my $received_data1 = 'Transfer Speed=81.9252432155658
2013/03/25 19:51:43,915|INFO|### STATUS: OK
2013/03/25 19:51:43,915|INFO|### DATA: Transfer Speed= 83.924363456758
2013/03/25 19:51:45,927|INFO|Checking FTP upload status...
2013/03/25 19:51:45,927|INFO|### INFO: Collect Throughput.
2013/03/25 19:51:45,927|INFO|Checking FTP upload status...
2013/03/25 19:51:45,927|INFO|### DATA: Transfer Speed=67.83685237005002';

my $regex =  qr/Transfer Speed=([0-9]{1,}[.][0-9]{1,}[^\n])/m;

if($received_data1 =~ $regex){
    #$received_data1 =~ s/$received_dat/$regex/gm;
    print $1;
}else{
    print "nothingFound";
}
```

From `print $1`, I am able to get only the first transfer speed, that is *81.9252432155658*, but not the others. I passed the modifiers `/gm` to let Perl know that the input string is multiline and to keep searching after the first match has been found. The regular expression in `$regex`works nicely on this website: http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php and I get an array of the matched values.

Getting the array is good enough since I can then loop through the array and print the values to a file or on the console.

I would appreciate any help.

PS: I have read most of the other Stack Exchange posts but they didn't help. I hope I did not duplicate any question. If there is a question that matches my request, I would appreciate the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `g` modifier on your match op. You can either call it repeatedly in scalar context

```
while ($received_data1 =~ /$regex/g) {
   print "$1\n";
}
```

or call it once in list context

```
for ($received_data1 =~ /$regex/g) {
   print "$_\n";
}
```

Notes:

- There's a space in front of one the speeds, but your pattern doesn't account for it.
- `/m` is useless to you, as you use neither `^` nor `$`.
- I don't know why you're using `[^\n]` in your pattern. It cuts off the last digits of the speed, which is probably not something you meant to do.

Comment: `ikegami`, thank you very much for the suggestion. Your suggestion worked like charm!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach

```
my @matches = $received_data1 =~ m/Transfer Speed=\s*(\d+\.\d+)/g;

if (@matches) {
    foreach my $m (@matches) {
        print "$m\n";
    }
} else {
    print "nothingFound";
}
```

Comment: That's also a brilliant answer. I like the array approach. An improvement to this would be: `@matches = $received_data1 =~ m/$regex/g;` where `$regex` is your neat regular expression you wrote.